# Masking property in Datastore

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a field in my collection that I would like to mask for responses. Here is a code example of what I need to achieve:

```
class Entity(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringField()

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.name [:2] + "***"
```

Expected result: name in database: John, name returned with API: Jo***

When I'm trying with code above getting 
`TypeError: Cannot set non-property name` when trying to create an Entity

Is there any smarter way to do it than masking name on every response?
Is it possible to modify values in _pre_get_hook() just for a response without changing a field in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is _post_get_hook, something along the lines of

```
def _post_get_hook(self,key,future):
   self.name = self.name[:2]+"***"
```

The fact that the name is modified is worrisome if a put is done on the same entity. I am not sure how your response is being constructed. If there is a way to filter some of the fields, then you can have a separate property that is derived based on the name in the _post_get_hook which is safer.